# Need example cordova-plugin-facebook4 for PhoneGap project

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap

I added a in the file config.xml:

```html
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="17"/>
...
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.5.0" />
...
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="1.7.4" source="npm">
  <param name="APP_ID" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
  <param name="APP_NAME" value="MyProg" />
</plugin>
```

The application is already registered in facebook and it was indicated above instead of X...

Please give an example of using the plugin - cordova-plugin-facebook4 for PhoneGap project.
I did not find a suitable example from this resource - https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-facebook4

Comment: $(document).on("click", "#snid", function(){

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```js
$(document).on("click", "#snid", function(){

        facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === "connected") {
                alert("Logged in, details:\n\n" + JSON.stringify(response.authResponse));
            } else {
                alert("Not logged in");
            }
        });

        var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
            alert("UserInfo: ", userData);
        };

        facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"], fbLoginSuccess,
            function loginError (error) {
                alert(error)
            }
        );
});
```

Show message: Not logged in

Then it hangs:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtXfF.png)